# PHP/MySQL Sort By Date

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I'm trying to pull records out of my database based on the oldest date.

The MySQl table looks like this:

status, date, last, url

1, 2010-12-30 17:59:54, 2011-01-03 06:26:04, site1.com

1, 2010-12-28 12:16:10, 2011-01-03, 06:25:24, site2.com

The date and last rows are datetime.

Here are two types of queries I tried:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM links WHERE status=1 ORDER BY last DESC LIMIT 0,25");
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM links WHERE status=1 ORDER BY DATE(last) DESC LIMIT 0,25");
```

The query works for the most part but always leaves some of the oldest records out...

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: Well, you're limiting at 25 results so you'll only see the last 25. The first query is enough, no need to use `DATE` on `last`.

Comment: The table has 100's of rows. I only wanted the 25 with the oldest dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume "last" means last clicked or updated right? I also think you want ascending order (12/20, 12/21) because you want the oldest dates first. "ORDER by last LIMIT 25" should be fine as ASC is implicit.

Comment: Yes, that is 100% what I want. I'll give it at try. :)

Answer (score 1):

What are date and last's data types? timestamp or ?

try this:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM links WHERE status=1 ORDER BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(last) DESC LIMIT 0,25");
```

Comment: Date and Last are both DATETIME.